# using angular new router with es6

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I am using NG6-starter package to learn angular 1.5 component using ES6.
Routing in this package is done by using stateProvider, now I want to use angular-new-router for routing.

I am doing this

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import Router from 'angular-new-router';
import homeComponent from './home.component';

let homeModule = angular.module('home', [
  Router
])

  .controller(($router) => {
    $router.config([
      {path: '/', component: 'homeComponent' }
    ])
  })

export default homeModule;
```

but it is not working...

Answer (score 1):

Use the file’s canonical path in your import statement.

**Example:**

```
import router from "@angular/router/angular1/angular_1_router";
```

**Note:** Things have changed since the question was asked. Check out the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngComponentRouter) for installation instructions.